# icon gets cut off by border

Tags: html, css

So basically I am trying to fit my active icon(star) in a progress bar but it seems to get cut off by the border. I'm not exactly sure how to fix this but if anyone knows how to fix this it would be much appreciated. I rather not rewrite the entirety of it since I got it how I want it minus the star portion.

```css
  .c_progressBar {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    counter-reset: step;
    width: 163px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    left: 221px;
  }
  .c_progressBar::before,
  .progress {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    height: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #999999;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .progress {
    background-color: #01539c;
    width: 0%;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  .progress-step {
    width: 1.1875rem;
    background-color: #999999;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .progress-step::before {
    content: "\a0";
  }
  .progress-step-active {
    background: url(https://i.ibb.co/2y8twZL/star.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  }
  .progress-step-check {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #01539C !important;
    transition: all 0.8s;
  }
  .progress-step-check::before {
    position: absolute;
    /*content: "\2713";*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 8px;
    left: 13px;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="c_progressBar">
    <div class="progress" id="progress"></div>
    <div class="progress-step progress-step-active"></div>
    <div class="progress-step"></div>
    <div class="progress-step"></div>
    <div class="progress-step"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What outcome are you after? Do you want a smaller star or a larger box?

Comment: I want the star to retain the same size as shown in the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background sizing seems to do the job. To maintain size, increase it on the active class. I've used some negative margin wizbang to shift position. You could also increase the size of *all* bullets and put some padding on the regular ones to shrink them.

```css
.c_progressBar {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  counter-reset: step;
  width: 163px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  left: 221px;
}

.c_progressBar::before,
.progress {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #999999;
  z-index: 1;
}

.progress {
  background-color: #01539c;
  width: 0%;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.progress-step {
  width: 1.1875rem;
  background-color: #999999;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.progress-step::before {
  content: "\a0";
}

.progress-step-active {
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/2y8twZL/star.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  /* <-------------------------------------------------------- HERE */
  background-size: cover;
  width: 1.6rem;
  margin: -0.2rem 0 -0.2rem -0.4rem;
}

.progress-step-check {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #01539C !important;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}

.progress-step-check::before {
  position: absolute;
  /*content: "\2713";*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 8px;
  left: 13px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="c_progressBar">
  <div class="progress" id="progress"></div>
  <div class="progress-step progress-step-active"></div>
  <div class="progress-step"></div>
  <div class="progress-step"></div>
  <div class="progress-step"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! Just how I want it and I removed `height: 1.6rem;` since it was cutting a little bit off on the edge. Looks better now